# "was applied not to" or "wasn't applied to"?

Tags: past-simple

I saw a sentence like this:

> The first recorded use of the term “Black Friday” **was applied not to** post-Thanksgiving holiday shopping but to financial crisis.

What is the difference between "wasn't applied to" and "was applied not to"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that 'wasn't applied to... but...' is less formal than 'was applied not to... but...'. Contractions (e.g. 'wasn't') are informal.

The first 'not' belongs to a common construction: *not ... but* which we can use to discuss that something happened which was **not** an expected, likely, or usual thing, **but** something else.

> When Joe fell in the sea, it was **not** dad that dived in and saved
> him, **but** Grandma.
>
> When I went for an Italian meal, I had **not** pizza, **but**
> spaghetti

Comment: I wonder whether the mean would totally changed if I say __wasn't applied to__ instead of __was applied not to__ ?

Comment: @user123960 - I am saying in my answer that the meaning would not change. It would just be less formal.